# Cannot override global article settings

Tags: joomla-3.3.x

I'm having trouble with the global option settings for articles in Joomla 3.3. I can set the global value for, say, displaying an email link beside an article, but the article-specific options that should override it don't seem to work.

This means I can display an email icon for every article, or for none.

Does anyone know of a work-around or whether an upcoming maintenance release might fix it?

Answer (score 1):

It works, just not the way you expect it to work.

I suspect you're using the "Single Article" menu item to display an article.

The "Single Article" menu item contains it's own options for displaying, for example, the email link, these override everything else.  The only options are Use Global, Show, Hide.

The "Category Blog" and "Featured Articles" menu items on the other hand, contain an additional option, "Use Article Settings".

Comment: You're right about the 'single article' menu item. It seems odd that there would be a set of options at the menu level that override the article level settings. Id' expect the article to have the final say. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's a bit tricky. The article options have the highest priority, unless the menu item does point to that specific article. In that case the menu item options override the article options.

Comment: Menu item always wins the settings battle. ;) And if you're ever running into a weird conflict, check and make sure you don't have a duplicate menu item going to the same article with different settings. I've made that mistake!