# Customize article options publish print and email links in Joomla 3.5

Tags: articles, joomla-3.5

I would like to display the articles in the front end, without the print and email links.
I have configured the publishing article options in Joomla for that, both article publish links disappear. Supposedly I have adjust this setting in Global Options and in Content->Articles->ArticleFrontPage options and this links continue showing in the display.

How could it be reached?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I can't get where is the Content->Article->ArticleFrontPage options you are mentioning in your question.

Regarding the front-end display:
 - Is this happening to a certain menu item? article?

Note that **Global Article Options** can be overriden by **menu item** or **article settings**.

Each article has its own **Show Icons** settings in its Options Tab.
Following any of the articles menu items have the same settings in their Options tab.

So, I would suggest you to have a look at corresponding articles, menu items options, for which you still see the icons in the front-end.

#### Hierarcy

As regarding the hierarchy of the options:

Global Settings come first, Article settings will override the Globals, Category settings come next and Menu Item settings are last. 
So a Menu Item's settings will override everything.

#### Template Overrides

As a last note: if changing settings doesn't seem to result to a change in the front-end, it can be due to template overrides. You might have a template that is overriding the layout output of the com_content component. So it's worth checking in the html folder of your template for a possible override.

#### More reading:

There is another similar question in JSE:

- **[Cannot override global article settings](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/1067/cannot-override-global-article-settings)**

These articles might be helpful in understanding Joomla Articles:

- [**Understanding Joomla Core Content Features**](https://www.joomlaplates.com/blog-news/understanding-joomla-core-content-features)
- [**Component Article Manager Options - Joomla Docs**](https://docs.joomla.org/Help35:Components_Article_Manager_Options)

Template overrides

- **[Template Overrides](https://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides)**
- **[Layout Overrides](https://docs.joomla.org/Layout_Overrides_in_Joomla)**

Comment: Yes, i have set the Global Article Settings and the Content->Article->ArticeX->Options Tab, and it continues showing the print/email Article links.    "ArticleFrontPage" is the title of the article that i have published in the front page - At this moment i haven't any menu in the Home Page (FrontPage)

Answer (score 0):

finally i accomplished to customize this setting, editing the icon.php file from the layout for the content component placed in my template folder: xampp-root-folder\htdocs\joomla\templates\ilus-design\html\layouts\joomla\content

web source: https://www.ostraining.com/blog/joomla/layout-overrides/